# How to find the right enum that selected on the spinner?

Tags: android

I define a spinner with values that i hold as a Enum.

1. This is how i define the enum:

   ```
    public enum EnumType
    {
        ENUM1("T1"),  
        ENUM2("T2"),  
        ENUM3("T3"),  
        ENUM4("T4"),  
        ENUM5("T5"),  

        private String _friendlyName;

        EnumType(String friendlyName) {
            this._friendlyName = friendlyName;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return _friendlyName;
        }
     }
   ```
2. I created the connection between the spinner object ( gui ) and the enum

   ```
      _arrayAdapterType = new ArrayAdapter<EnumType>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, EnumType.values());

      _enumTypeSpinner.setAdapter(_arrayAdapterType);
   ```
3. I trying to get the right enum when the user select some item from the spinner -  **but this not working and i get no item on the switch..case even when i one of the item was selected**

   ```
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

   EnumTypeitem = EnumType.values()[position];

   switch(item)
   {
       case ENUM1:
           break;
       case ENUM2:
           break;
       case ENUM3:
           break;
       case ENUM4:
           break;
       case ENUM5:
           break;
   }

   // Fail to get the right item on the switch..case !!!
   ```

Comment: I had a question but I found my answer in your question! thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have problem in other things, because this work for me .

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Spinner _enumTypeSpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id._enumTypeSpinner);
    _enumTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            EnumType item = EnumType.values()[position];

            switch (item) {
                case ENUM1:
                    Log.v("MyActivity","Selected item :"+item);
                    break;
                case ENUM2:
                    Log.v("MyActivity","Selected item :"+item);
                    break;
                case ENUM3:
                    Log.v("MyActivity","Selected item :"+item);
                    break;
                case ENUM4:
                    Log.v("MyActivity","Selected item :"+item);
                    break;
                case ENUM5:
                    Log.v("MyActivity","Selected item :"+item);
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<EnumType> _arrayAdapterType = new ArrayAdapter<EnumType>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, EnumType.values());
    _enumTypeSpinner.setAdapter(_arrayAdapterType);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following

```
public enum EnumType
{
     ENUM1("T1"),  
     ENUM2("T2"),  
     ENUM3("T3"),  
     ENUM4("T4"),  
     ENUM5("T5");  

     private String _friendlyName;
     private List<EnumType> _values;

     private EnumType(String friendlyName) {
         this._friendlyName = friendlyName;
     }

     public List<EnumType> getValues(){
         if(_values == null){
             _values = new ArrayList<>();
             _values.add(ENUM1);
             _values.add(ENUM2);
             _values.add(ENUM3);
             _values.add(ENUM4);
             _values.add(ENUM5);
         }  

         return _values 
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return _friendlyName;
     }
}
```

In your adapter use getValues() method to get the list. Keep your switch case identical to what you already have. This should work.

Comment: did you rad the question ? because there is not connection between my question and what you wrote :(

Comment: "I trying to get the right enum when the user select some item from the spinner". I am answering this. You can not compare two enum objects directly because although they might be referring to same enum type but they could be different instances of that enum. enum in Java is not very different than class. I had faced similar issue in past so just thought of suggesting things that worked for me. Making the constructor private makes sure that we are not instantiating duplicate instances of same enum type and it will ensure that your switch case works fine for comparison of enum types.